# How to stop truncating strings when I use the group by function

Tags: python, group-by, nlp, jupyter-notebook

I have a table with columns: Location, Basic quals, Preferred quals, and Responsibilities.
The last three columns have string entries that I tokenized, I want to group the columns by Location. When I do this my strings Truncate eg. "we want an individual who knows python and java." turns into "we want an individual..."
How do I avoid this from happening?

```py
grouped_location=pd.DataFrame(df1['Pref'].groupby(df1['Location']))

grouped_location.columns = ['Loaction','Pref']
grouped_location=grouped_location.set_index('Loaction')
grouped_location.iat[0,0]
```

I expect to get 
17    [Experience, in, design, verification,, includ (full entry)]

but what I get is:

17    [Experience, in, design, verification,, includ...

Comment: Post the missing code because the error isn't in the code you added. Post also the table in text format (and possibly as picture).

Answer (score 0):

Try saving out the dataframe to csv, it's probably only the display configuration that's truncating it.